# Step with click functionality in intro.js

Tags: intro.js

Does anyone know how to add an step to intro.js that can open a menu when going to the target element. I have button on the left corner of my website. When user click that button a menu will be displayed. I could not find a way in intro.js to open that menu when intro is on that step.

Answer (score 4):

> It should be emphasized that the functionality is not officially
>   supported.

### Emulate a click on a specific step:

After investigating how to **emulate a click** when IntroJS is **in a specific step** see: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/pull/380/files?short_path=04c6e90

The proposal in this feature commit is to use the:
Attribute `data-click`: **Show a click animation over the tooltip**.

### Trigger a function on each step:

I'll recommend that you emulate a click or whatever you want to do dynamically: **firing a function** at each step, this allows you to do more complex things.

We use `onchange: function(){...}` for this.

You can set a function callback or hard-code the actions to emulate a click on the element inside the `function(){}` block.

> Alter step events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42324402/3172310
>   
>   Callback on step changes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17157644/3172310

Working Example: http://www.observatoriodeviolencias.net/

Comment: Thanks ...This really help me.